# Angular-Elements are not refreshing after aborted drag&drop

Tags: angularjs, drag-and-drop, ngdraggable

I have the following angular-List (reduced the content to make it better readable):

```
 <div ng-repeat="element in bigBlock.Elements track by $index"
                         class="singleBlockElement"

                         ng-drop="dragSource=='Block'"
                         ng-drop-success="To($index, $data, bigBlock)">
                        <div class="bbRange">&nbsp;</div>
                        <i class="fa {{GetImage(element)}}" />
                        <div ng-drag="element.ElementType!=='placeholder'"
                             ng-drag-data="element"
                             ng-drag-start="Start()"
                             ng-drag-success="From(element,bigBlock, $index, bigBlock.$index)"
                             ng-drag-stop="Stop(element, bigBlock, $index, bigBlock.$index)"
                             class="cutOff">
                            {{element.Title}}
                        </div>
                        <div class="edit ng-show="GetLinkText(element, true)">
                            <span class="isvisible">
                                <i title="{{element.Present?'Präsentieren':'Nicht präsentieren'}}" class="fa fa-{{element.Present?'eye':'eye-slash'}}"></i>
                            </span>
                            <a href="#" ng-click="Edits.Element(element, true)">{{GetLinkText(element,true)}}</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

This is how it looks like:
[image]
This is while dragging:
[image]
And this is how it looks like when I simply don't drop like described below:
[image]

I can now (successfully) drag & drop the two elements ("Welcome" and "Go Away") inside that block changing the order of these two.

But if I abort the drag/drop. e.g. Dragging "Welcome" and not moving it downwards or moving it to an area where I cannot drop (outside the block) the text "Welcome" disappears.

There are no errors. The drop is just not happing (as expected), but Angular seems to be unable to redisplay the text of that element. ({{element.Title}})

I event tried forcing a refresh using $apply(), but this did not change a thing (not creating an error either).

However, if I do ANYTHING on the page like clicking on an edit-button or anything else that causes an event, the date is correctly shown again.

So it looks like a refresh issue for me.

I am using ngDraggable for this (https://github.com/fatlinesofcode/ngDraggable)

(Update: Analyzing the page source in Developer Console of Chrome the text still seems to be there and even "should" be visible (display:block), so this might be more of a browser-issue (chrome) than an angular-issue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a pure Browser/CSS-Issue and not an Angular-Issue. I solved this by forcing the browser to refresh the parent container:

```
$('.mm-Right')[0].style.display = 'none';
$('.mm-Right')[0].offsetHeight; 
$('.mm-Right')[0].style.display = 'block';
```

where my structure is

```
<div class='mm-Right'>
<div class='singleBlockElement>[..]</div>
<div class='singleBlockElement>[..]</div>
<div class='singleBlockElement>[..]</div>
</div>
```

That **did** solve the problem but looks like cheating for me. I would prefer that this bug not even appears instead of hiding the symptoms. So I am happy to accept any better answer for that problem.